# Using Civicrm_api3 in onAjax[Name] plugin function

Tags: api, joomla, php, ajax, plugin

I created a plugin which provides custom validation for civicrm forms.  Part of the jQuery validation on the plugin makes an AJAX call to the plugin.  The plugin calls its onAjax[Name] method.  In the onAjax[Name] method, I want to use civicrm_api3( ... ).  However, the system returns a fatal error

Call to undefined function civicrm_api3()

How do I use civicrm_api3 in the above context?  Do I need to import some class files?  The same code works if the validation occurs when the form is submitted with the submit button instead of AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

Call `civicrm_initialize()` before using `civicrm_api3()` (or other CiviCRM functions).

This function is defined in the various CMS plugins (eg `civicrm.module`) and will load required files then initialize CiviCRM, after which you can make API calls.

Since booting the CRM adds overhead, it's best to only do when CRM is required - hence the separate function.

Comment: Civicrm_initialize() generates a fatal error call to undefined function civicrm_initialize()

Comment: Can you paste the url you trying to call on ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following.  It is important to note that my current working directory was that of the website not the plugin directory, so when I did the require_once and conf_path, I had to take that into account for class.api.php and civicrm.settings.php (i.e. my path was like administrator/.../class.api.php)

```
require_once 'your/civicrm/folder/api/class.api.php';
$api = new civicrm_api3(array(
  // Specify location of "civicrm.settings.php".
  'conf_path' => 'your/sites/default',
));
$apiParams = array(
  'first_name' => 'Alice',
  'last_name' => 'Roberts',
);
if ($api->Contact->Get($apiParams)) {
  //each key of the result array is an attribute of the api
  echo "\n contacts found ".$api->count;
}
else {
  echo $api->errorMsg();
}
```

It really should be documented somewhere that you cannot bootstrap CiviCRM in an onAjax[Name] method.  In my case, when I tried it, the submit button for the form lost its functionality.